# How to retrieve characters before and after a forward slash

Tags: c#

I have this string which comes from the datareader: [http://win-167nve0l50/dev/dev/new/1st Account](http://win-167nve0l50/dev/dev/new/1st%20Account)

I want the get the file name, which is "1st Account"
and the list name, which is "new" and the list address which is "http://win-167nve0l50/dev/dev/". This is the code I am using:
How do I retrieve the site address and the list name.

```
//getting the file URL from the data reader
string fileURL = dataReader["File URL"].ToString();

//getting the list address/path 
string listAdd = fileURL.Substring(fileURL.IndexOf("/") + 1);

//getting the file name
 string fileName = fileURL.Substring(fileURL.LastIndexOf("/") + 1);
```

Comment: Have you tried the URI class?

Comment: A regular expression is probably the easiest way, but not sure about best performance. You could use `LastIndexOf` to get the index of the last `/` in the string and work from there back...

Comment: i have tried, but realized that i cant use it because the address path my not always be the same as the one i used on the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If dealing with Uri, use the according class ...

```
Uri u = new Uri(dataReader["File URL"].ToString());
```

... and access the desired parts of the path by Segments array

```
string listAdd = u.Segments[3]; // remove trailing '/' if needed
string fileName = u.Segments[4];
```

... or in case you need to make sure to handle arbitrary path length

```
string listAdd = u.Segments[u.Segments.Length - 2];
string fileName = u.Segments[u.Segments.Length - 1];
```

Comment: i tried using this segment, but Uri u = new Uri(dataReader["File URL"].ToString()); throws an exception "dataReader["File URL"] threw an exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException'

Comment: You did not show what's behind `dataReader["File URL"].ToString()` so I assumed you have got that part working. My solution is tested against the mentioned example URI `http://win-167nve0l50/dev/dev/new/1st Account`. Place a breakpoint on that line and inspect your datareader for the correct column name or column index.

Answer (score 1):

You can get all sorts of info easily using the [Uri Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
var uri = new Uri(dataReader["File URL"].ToString());
```

then you can get various bits from the Uri  object eg.

- `Uri.Authority` - Gets the Domain Name System (DNS) host name or IP address and the port number for a server.
- `Uri.Host` - Gets the host component of this instance
- `Uri.GetLeftPart()` - Gets the specified portion of a Uri instance.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [`Uri`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri?view=netframework-4.7) class
It's main purpose is to handle composed resource `string`s.

You can use:

- [`Uri.Host`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri.host?view=netframework-4.7#System_Uri_Host) to obtain the host address string
- [`PathAndQuery`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri.pathandquery?view=netframework-4.7#System_Uri_PathAndQuery) to getthe absolute path of the file on the server and the query information sent with the request

All the [properties here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri?view=netframework-4.7#properties_)

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it with [Regex](https://regex101.com/r/VD4YBf/1/):

```
string str = "http://win-167nve0l50/dev/dev/new/1st Account";
Regex reg = new Regex("^(?<address>.*)\\/(?<list>[^\\/]*)\\/(?<file>.*)$");
var match = reg.Match(str);
if (match.Success)
{
    string address = match.Groups["address"].Value;
    string list = match.Groups["list"].Value;
    string file = match.Groups["file"].Value;
}
```

Comment: how can i use this if the string is not really known... i get the string from the dataReader, where i populate from a SQL table

Comment: Just use string you read from dataReader: `string str = dataReader["File URL"].ToString();`

Comment: that string throws a System.IndexOutOfRangeException

Comment: Exception is thrown from `dataReader["File URL"]`. Please check how you get data for reader. https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/f01t4cfy(v=vs.110).aspx